# ifconfig shows UP while ip link shows DOWN

Tags: networking, linux-networking, interface, ifconfig

I am looking at the state of an interface on a Linux system. When I use the `ifconfig` command it shows that the link is UP.

```
master $ ifconfig docker0
docker0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:b9:25:be:2d
          inet addr:172.18.0.1  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

However, when I run the `ip link` command , it is down.

```
master $ ip link show docker0
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default
    link/ether 02:42:b9:25:be:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: This is normal, if you have no containers running on that network. It will change when you start a container. Also `ifconfig` is 10 years obsolete, often displays wrong information, and should not be used anymore.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Please don't answer the questions in the comment section. You can read about your [commenting privileges here](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/comment). Note that this information is also presented to you when you try to write a comment: _Avoid answering questions in comments._ Please be mindful that as a diamond moderator you set an example to other users.

Comment: @pipe This comment does not suffice as an answer, which is why it is a comment. If you have further concerns, feel free to post on meta.

Answer (score 20):

In the ifconfig `UP` flag means the administrative status, not link status. If you have 'link up', then `RUNNING` flag is present in the `ifconfig` output. Anyway, `ifconfig` is deprecated, use the `ip` tool.

In the `ip` tool link status is shown by flags `LOWER_UP` and `NO-CARRIER`.

Comment: So what does it mean when ifconfig says `UP` and `ip link` says down? I could not follow

Comment: The ifconfig `UP` flag means the interface is administratively enabled.  But `ip link` shows more options: `UP`/`DOWN` flag is the administrative status, `LOWER-UP`/`NO-CARRIER` shows state of underlayer media (e.g. ethernet link status), `state Up`/`state Down` shows full functionality.